# json parse from combobox data

Tags: json, parsing

want to parse a JSON string in combobox to 'text'. The response is something like
How can I parse the JSON and extract its 'text' values?

```
 var restClient = new RestClient("https://cbsservis.tkgm.gov.tr/megsiswebapi.v2/api/idariYapi/ilListe");
        var restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        var restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
        restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "text/json");
        var jArray = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(restResponse.Content);
        dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(restResponse.Content);

        dynamic jsonResponse2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(string JObject);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response can be represented by classes like this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Feature[] features { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Crs crs { get; set; }
}

public class Crs
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public Properties1 properties { get; set; }
}

public class Geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public object[][][] coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class Properties1
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Hence your code can be changed to:

```
 var restClient = new RestClient("https://cbsservis.tkgm.gov.tr/megsiswebapi.v2/api/idariYapi/ilListe");
    var restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    var restResponse = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
    restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "text/json");
 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(restResponse.Content);
```

You will receive the object like this:

[image: Parsed object]

And then you can loop through properties to get desired text.

Comment: sorry i failed!!! comboBoxİL.DataSource =??? what should I write instead of a question mark public string text { get; set; } 
I can list the field

Comment: I don't see any DataSource in your question

Comment: I'm trying to transfer text fields from combobox